# Open image file as binary, store image as string of bytes, save the image - possible in plain C?

Tags: c, image, io, binaryfiles, binary-data

I would like to read an image, lets say, `picture.png` in C. I know I can open it in binary mode, and then read - it's pretty simple.

But I need something more: I would like to be able to read the image once, store it in my code, for example, in `*.h` file, as 'string of bytes', for example:

`unsigned char image[] = "0x87 0x45 0x56 ... ";`

and then, be able to just do:

1. delete physical file I read from disk,
2. save `image` into file - it will create my file once again,

EVEN if I removed image from disk (deleted physical file `picture.png` I read earlier) I will still be able to create an image on disk, simply by writing my `image` array into file using binary mode. Is that possible in pure C? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Why not store it as a *binary* array? E.g. `const unsigned char[] = { 0x87, 0x45, 0x56, ... };`

Comment: or `unsigned char image[] = "\x87\x45\x56 ... ";`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Ok but how can I read it and save it to have such array?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: so you say that I can simply open my file using binary mode, read it into an array. Ok, but hos to make a static array from it? Some kind of `const` variable I can paste in my `*.h` file and use it even if I dont have the physical image file anymore?

Comment: My advice is to *not* put it as a `static` variable in a header file, because then that image will be duplicated in each translation unit that uses that header file. Instead put it in a single translation unit, and have an `extern` declaration in the header file. Will save you a *lot* of space in the executable.

Comment: but There may be limited in length to a string literal by the compiler. E.g MSVC : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx08afx2.aspx

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Ok, dont store it in `*.h` file - got it :) But is it possible to keep it in an array? the images Im talking about here are quite small, 100px * 25 px

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's possible, but it's a bit unclear what you're after.

There are stand-alone programs that convert binary data to C source code, you don't need to implement that. But doing it that way of course means that the image becomes a static part of your program's executable.

If you want it to be more dynamic, like specifying the filename to your program when it's running, then the whole thing about converting to C source code becomes moot; your program is already compiled. C programs can't add to their own source at run-time.

**UPDATE** If all you want to do is load a file, hold it in memory and then write it back out, all in the same run of your program, that's pretty trivial.

You'd use `fopen()` to open the file, `fseek()` to go to the end, `ftell()` to read the size of the file. Then `rewind()` it to the start, `malloc()` a suitable buffer, `fread()` the file's contents into the buffer and `fclose()` the file. Later, `fopen()` a new output file, and `fwrite()` the buffer into that before using `fclose()` to close the file. Then you're done. You can do it again, as many times as you like. It can be an image, a program, a document or any other kind of file, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I think you misnderstood me, maybe I'm unclear here - if so - sorry for that :( Lets say I have an image, I read it using the binary mode and want to save it into an array as string of bytes. Then, I can simple remove physicall file from disk but since I have its binary representation it should be easy to restore it, just writing to file the whole array I read earlier - is that possible? Dont bother to ask further questions, I dont know how to explain it easier

Comment: Hmm, right. But what if I would like to read it in one run, and save in another, without pre-reading in this second run?

Answer (score 2):

There's even a special format for this task, called [XPM](http://old.koalateam.com/lehors/xpm.html) and a library to manipulate these files. But remember due to its nature it's suitable only for relatively small images. But yes, it was used for years in X Window System to provide icons. Well, those old good days icons were 16x16 pixels wide and contained no more than 256 colors :)

Answer (score 1):

**pic2h.c** :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage >pic2h image.png image.h\n");
        return -1;
    }
    FILE *fi = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    FILE *fo = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    int ch, count = 0;
    fprintf(fo, "extern unsigned char image[];\n");
    fprintf(fo, "unsigned char image[] =");
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fi))){
        if(count == 0)
            fprintf(fo, "\n\"");
        fprintf(fo, "\\x%02X", ch);
        if(++count==24){
            count = 0;
            fprintf(fo, "\"");
        }
    }
    if(count){
        fprintf(fo, "\"");
    }
    fprintf(fo, ";\n");

    fclose(fo);
    fclose(fi);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**resave.c** :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "image.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage >resave image.png\n");
        return 0;
    }
    size_t size = sizeof(image)-1;
    FILE *fo = fopen(argv[1], "wb");
    fwrite(image, size, 1, fo);
    fclose(fo);
    return 0;
}
```